# Fast AJAX refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What is the best way to do Ajax request refreshing?

I have the following right now:

```
setInterval(function() {
$.post('upload.php', function(finish)
{})},30);
```

Unfortunately it’s too slow for me because I need it to refresh in 0.030 seconds at most.

How can I improve the performance to meet my needs?

Comment: Poor server getting hammered.

Comment: What are you trying to do? DoS the server?

Comment: Yeah, reduce the timing for your setInterval function. 30 is 30 milleseconds which is 0.030s - do you need something faster? 30 in the context of the OP is milleseconds (fixed my typo)

Comment: @JayBlanchard 30 ms is not 0.003 s.

Comment: @Jay, 30 msec is 0.030 s... not 0.003s

Comment: please provide your scenario as in explaining what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Have you ever heard about sockets? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: i have a multiplayer game, and its need ot get positions of other players

Comment: @BendegúzSzabó Ajax isn't the right way to do it if you need updates every 2 seconds or less, possibly even longer due to network speeds

Comment: @BendegúzSzabó As epascarello said, WebSockets are **a lot BETTER** than requesting the server every 30 milliseconds!

Comment: 2 seconds are wrong, its too laggy, the 0.03 second is the continuous for eyes.

Comment: @BendegúzSzabó That's my point. Ajax isn't any good when you need updates that fast. use websockets or build your game in such a way that it doesn't need ajax updates for positioning of other players. I doubt even websockets will be as fast as you want it to be because the data will still have to travel across the line which could take anywhere from 10ms to 10 seconds depending on location and network speed.

Answer (score 0):

based on your comments about wanted to request information for a multiplayer game,

normally clients will do some dead-heading on every field that needs some sort of web-update. This is what 'lag' is in normal gaming. The different between what the player's client thinks other are doing before it gets an update of what really is going on.

30 msec is a very quick timeframe to be doing this over a webserver and should be done using WebSockets (as others have pointed out in the comments).